# Is it possible to layer an SVG with a transparent background over a Google Map?

Tags: google-maps, svg

Instead of the using Google Map's polyline API, is it possible to layer an SVG image over the map with a library like d3?

Are there any examples of this in the wild?

Comment: I'm sorry this is a bad question -- but could someone tell me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course it is possible. In regards to any examples in the wild, [Google has an example](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#CustomOverlays) of creating a custom overlay using an image. If you want to use SVG or even Canvas then there is really no difference you can manipulate the DOM in any way you please :)

Comment: But if the user wanted to move the Google map that was under the SVG layer, would this be a little tricky?

Comment: I don't see why. The z-index is handled perfectly by Googles API if you look at the DOM the tiles are organized to allow interaction with the map.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible for some time because of bug in GoogleMaps. If SVG is large (car route), svg disappear from some zoom level in some browsers (namely Opera 12+ and iPad Safari). Polyline works fine in all browsers a and same SVG in same zoom works fine when tested outside GoogleMaps.